# How to remove the delimiter in JOIN function when there is no name in google sheet?

Tags: join, google-sheets, delimiter

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to combine the data in Column D in range `F2:I7`. I'm using `JOIN` function but there will be a lot of delimiter when there is no data. May I know how to automate the range in `JOIN` function so that it will automatically expand when data exist so that there will be no unnecessary delimiter? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

This is the link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/153oaJwVfux-_0OCMFsoedvGcJT0Zr-Cv0SaTY2WLVb4/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",true,D2:D)
```

### References

- [TEXTJOIN (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en)